# How to select non-repeating values based on one column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

| intStudentCode | strFavoriteSocialMedia |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Facebook |
| 1 | Instagram |
| 2 | Twitter |
| 3 | TikTok |
| 4 | Youtube |
| 5 | Facebook |
| 6 | TikTok |
| 6 | Youtube |

The table has 8 lines. I want a table having only non-repeating intStudentCode. For Example:

| intStudentCode | strFavoriteSocialMedia |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Facebook |
| 2 | Twitter |
| 3 | TikTok |
| 4 | Youtube |
| 5 | Facebook |
| 6 | TikTok |

I dont have preference if the strFavoriteSocialMedia for intStudentCode = 1 is Facebook or Instagram. The same to intStudentCode = 6. All I want is retrieve a single student line based on intStudentCode. PS: I am using SQL Server 2012, but if you have the solution for another DBMS, it also help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you don't have a preference if the `strFavoriteSocialMedia` a simple aggregation should do the trick

```
Select intStudentCode
      ,strFavoriteSocialMedia = max( strFavoriteSocialMedia )
 From  YourTable
 Group By intStudentCode
```

Or another option using `WITH TIES` in concert with `row_number()`

```
Select top 1 with ties *
 From  YourTable
 Order By row_number() over (partition by intStudentCode order by strFavoriteSocialMedia)
```

Comment: You're awesome, It works!! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

To add-up, Another way that would help using `Row_Number`

```
SELECT intStudentCode,strFavoriteSocialMedia  FROM (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY intStudentCode ORDER BY strFavoriteSocialMedia) as r,* 
FROM Table
)TEMP WHERE r=1
```